# Low-cost SaaS for a low-volume mailing list?

Tags: gui, saas, mailing-list

As the title says, I am looking for a low-cost SaaS for a low-volume mailing list. In this context, SaaS means I don't have to muck around with mailman configurations and DNS (for the latter reason, I *don't* want to use a custom domain name, unless the configuration is as simple as delegating a subdomain).

I am looking for an "old-style" forum-by-email mailing list, not just a newsletter where users don't have a talkback possibility.

Comment: Does the mailing list need to be private, or public?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Public. Anyone should be able to register.

Comment: An public archive of past messages is also fine, but not a requirement.

Comment: maybe also a newsletter-manager like [phpList.org](https://www.phplist.org/) (can be used for self-hosting or SaaS) suits your needs...?

Comment: Can you please clarify which kind of list you mean?  The old style, where there's a discussion on the list (like forum-by-mail), or the new style, which is all push from one source (like marketing or newsletter)?

Comment: @CPerkins Old style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my various open source projects, I have about 20 mailing lists using [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/). I have no complain.

- Almost no configuration
- 100% SaaS
- Free
- No ads included in the emails
- Built-in antispam works well
- People can choose to receive emails or just watch on the web, or receive digests
- Public archive
- Search works well
- Any traffic volume
- Any number of subscribers
- Attachments work
- Anyone can post, but as an admin you can choose to moderate all posts and white-list people with a single click.

Comment: Great answer. How come I didn't think of Google Groups?

Answer (score 1):

Please check out our service, [Groups.io](https://groups.io). We have more features than Google Groups and Yahoo Groups.

Comment: Are there any particular features that you offer beyond what the accepted answer lists for google groups? the biggest difference i see that may be a dealbreaker is that groups.io is a subscription compared to the free google groups

Comment: Apologies - i was mistaken about the pricing - there is a free tier mentioned at the bottom of the pricing page